# Can't ping from subnet

Tags: networking

I try to explain it shortly.
I have a virtual server 20.04 with two interfaces.

eth0 is 192.168.1.5, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.1.1 and dns is also 192.168.1.1.

eth1 is 10.0.0.1, 255.0.0.0, 192.168.1.5 with dns 192.168.1.1

I can ping -I eth0 google.com but can't from eth1, only the ip will be resolved.

I tried the ipforwarding commands found on askubuntu and other sites.

I think maybe the default gateway of eth1 is wrong. If so what should it be? Or what iptables/other commands I should run?

**Edit**: net.ipv4.ip_forward is 1.
(I'm thinking of playing with the routing table later on.)

Following I've tried already always both directions i/o.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

Probably half of it has got nothing to do with what I want.

Isn't a bridge is what I need in this case?

Comment: "Isn't a bridge is what I need in this case?" Nobody can tell you if this is what you need. You may try to specify your question. Otherwise I wrote the answer explaining why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what your actual goal is.  Why are you using 2 interfaces?  Do you want load balancing?  Redundancy?  Do you physically have access to 2 different networks of `192.168.1.x` and `10.0.0.x`?  Is your host computer a `10.0.0.x` IP and your VM is showing `192.168.1.x` IP?  VMs by default setup in their own network, but you can normally change the settings to the NIC to be bridged, then your VM can be on the same network as your host system is.  Please add more details to your question explaining what your goal is.  Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do..
If you just want to have a computer with two interfaces then you do not need to specify routing on the second card.
If you want this computer to serve as a bridge then you should ask about setting up a bridge, and you may probably also be interested in firewall / NAT DHCP and the like.
Please clarify.

Comment: i want this computer to be the gateway / bridge between the internet any my environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. The gateway needs to be in the same subnet. 
   `10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0` network has an address range from `10.0.0.1` to `10.255.255.254`.
2. You cannot have 2 default gateways within the same network namespace or VRF. 
   If you wish to have this system connected to 2 networks, you need to configure routes.
   Even with routes, the `next hop` will still need to be within the same subnet as outgoing interface.
3. Enabling ip_forward allows your system to act as a router. If IP packet which is not destined to this system will arrive on the interface, and routing table will have an entry for its destination, the system will forward that packet to the `next hop`.